# WIX Velo - Extracting Domain from User Email - Regex Issue

Tags: javascript, regex, velo

I am trying to retrieve the domain of my site users in order to assign them specific organisation based privileges.

If their email address is email@example.com, I want to extract example. If it's email@ex.ample.com I want to extract ex.ample

The regex I have is (?<=@)[^.]*.[^.]*(?=.)

But I'm struggling to integrate this into the code. My code as follows:

```
$w.onReady(async function () {
 let userEmail = await memberData.loginEmail;
    retrieveTeamFromEmail(userEmail);
    $w('#userAccountSetupIntroText').text = ("Let's set up your account. We have your company as " +
        userEmail + ".\n\nTell us a little more about yourself.");
})

function retrieveTeamFromEmail(userEmail) {
 return userEmail
        .replace(?<=@)[^.]*.[^.]*(?=\.);
}
```

I'm getting an error at .replace:

[.replace error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqsJS.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using replace, you can match the part using a capture group.

```
[^\s@]@([^\s@]+)\.[a-z]{2,}
```

The pattern matches:

- `[^\s@]@` Match any char except a whitspace char or @
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `[^\s@]+` Match 1+ times any char except a whitspace char or @
- `)` Close group 1
- `\.[a-z]{2,}` Match a dot (note to escape the dot) and 2 or more chars a-z

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fnM4LJ/1)

```js
const pattern = /[^\s@]@([^\s@]+)\.[a-z]{2,}/;

function retrieveTeamFromEmail(s) {
  const m = s.match(/[^\s@]@([^\s@]+)\.[a-z]{2,}/, s);
  return m ? m[1] : s;
}
[
  "email@example.com",
  "email@ex.ample.com",
  "test"
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(retrieveTeamFromEmail(s))
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't cover things like name@example.co.uk.

Comment: @John That is correct, that is also the case for the pattern that the OP uses. This certainly does not match only valid email addresses. There are more sophisticated patterns for that.

Comment: @Thefourthbird could you share a pattern that would give the email domain in the instance that the TLD is .com, .co.za, .co.uk, etc?

Answer (score -1):

How about something not as fancy as a regex:

```js
function retrieveTeamFromEmail(userEmail) {
    const at = userEmail.indexOf('@');
    const dot = userEmail.lastIndexOf('.');
    return userEmail.substring(at, dot);
}
```

Comment: Looking into this more both the regex and this function wont return the desired result in the instance the TLD is .co.uk or .com.na, etc.